# What's the age recomendation for my app?

Tags: math-puzzle, games

I've developed an [android math game called MathLab](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sl.cells) that has started to gain popularity. It's a simple fill-in-the-grid puzzle with variable cell sizes and locking cells. My daughter's math teacher got very excited about it, so she asked me to add age/grade information to each difficulty setting so that she can recommend it to parents. I'd be very thankful to anyone who can provide me with that kind of rating info.

Also, does this seem suitable for the Google Play for Education program?

Comment: I like this question, but probably no one here will be willing to download and play the game just to rate the levels. Can you edit your question to include more details of how the game is played? What exactly is the difficulty that the player will be facing at each level, or on each difficulty setting? How did *you* decide to make the difficulty settings distint?

Comment: I would choose a [different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATHLAB) [name](http://help.mathlab.us/).

Comment: This looks wonderful, but I agree with both Dave and Mike: First, in addition to the name being a bit ambiguous Pearsons has a piece of software called "My Math Lab" that this may get confused with. Second, why don't you ask your daughter's teacher what grade levels she would recommend? She's played the game and is in a good position to what grade level the requisite math fits in.

Comment: It seems that the best way to assign age or grade information to each level would be to test each level on children with different ages and grades.

Comment: Let players find their own level. Have a login system. Start everyone at the same super easy level like in most video games. When they have mastered one level, automatically promote them to the next.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro yes, I am aware of the existence of that wonderful piece of software :) what name would you suggest?

Comment: @DanChristensen you are pretty much right, although I've already divided the difficulty in 4: Human, Technical, Engineer, I am Math! Doing what you suggested will change the process entirely and most likely upset existing users. Dividing these into 4 age ranges would be the best solution imo. 6-8, 8-10, 10-14 and grown-up is what I was thinking, although math isn't something that grows on people with age, "I am Math!" level is pretty complicated for most. And then there's the "Pi" level which you can play until you lose: it just draws numbers from the Pi decimals endlessly

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche I've done that, see my previous comment on my selected age ratings. I'd like to hear more opinions though

Comment: Regarding name suggestions, an immediate thought was [tick-tack-math](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22tick-tack-math%22) (which I thought clever, but apparently not). Then I thought of [math bingo](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22math+bingo%22) and [crossword math](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22crossword+math%22), neither of which isn't that good of a fit, but it seems these have also been taken. Maybe ask at your website for ideas, perhaps saying you'll give some kind of prize (or credit) to the one you choose.

Comment: FYI, "neither of which isn't that good of a fit" should be "neither of which is that good of a fit".

Comment: @Nick A 12-year-old stuck in the age group labelled 6 to 8 years will quickly become discouraged. Better to call it Level 1 as in many video games.

Comment: @DanChristensen see my difficulty naming choices, and each difficulty has levels 1 to 99